# Optimize website for mobile landscape view

Tags: android, html, ios, iphone

I am optimizing my website for mobile use. On most devices the portrait view is perfect but when I choose landscape view the styling is messed up.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Get My Look - Home</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="download.html">Download</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
 <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
    <p>
        &copy; 2017 - Get My Look
    </p>
 <div id="links">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/getmylookapp/" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/getmylookapp" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/getmylookapp/" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/getmylookapp" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/snapchat.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: #00B2EE;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Verdana";
}

#header{
    position:absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

#links{
    position:absolute;
    top: -150px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

p{
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

#social{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

#header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

#header ul li a {
    color: black;
    margin: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header ul li.selected a {
    border-bottom: solid 2px #000000;
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#links ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#links ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px;
}

#content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

h1{
    padding-top: 50px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #00B2EE;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #009ACD;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
#header, #content, #footer {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
```

}

So for every device that visits the site that has a screen size less that 1020px, adjust accordingly.

Portrait
[image]

Landscape
[image]
[image]

What CSS do I need to add to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you could use jquery to give a dynamic height to your body. The problem on landscape devices is that the footer is at the end of the body, but the body height is smaller than the webpage height which gives you this awful design.

So you could do this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Get My Look - Home</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var h = $(window).height();
        $('body').css({
            "min-height": h
        })
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="download.html">Download</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>
        &copy; 2017 - Get My Look
    </p>
    <div id="links">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/getmylookapp/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/getmylookapp" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/getmylookapp/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/getmylookapp" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/snapchat.png" alt="" width="64" height="64">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    body {
        position: relative;
    }

    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

That way, your footer would always stay on the bottom of your page

Comment: The issue is still there. This code didn't adjust anything.

Comment: it would probably help if you gave the rest of the code, instead of just one line of css